# Display a chain of little mountains with an odd number on the top of it!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

First line is made with `ceil(n/2)` elements where each element is: `<space><odd-number><space>`

Second line is made with `ceil(n/2)` elements, but each element is `/ \` only.

You may assume `n >= 0` and `n <= 10`.

#### Examples

Input: 3

```
 1  3
/ \/ \
```

Input: 10

```
 1  3  5  7  9
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

---

Example in Python 3, 103 bytes:

```
lambda a:print("".join([" "+str(i)+" "for i in range(1,a+1,2)]+["\n"]+["/ \\"for i in range(1,a+1,2)]))
```

Shortest code in bytes wins :)

Comment: Can you assume all input will be less then 11?

Comment: Yup, all input will be less than 11 !

Comment: Welcome to the site! Our default for [tag:code-golf] is to count in bytes, not characters. If you want to override that, though, it's your choice. Also, I would recommend the [Sandbox](//meta.ppcg.lol/q/2140) the next time :)

Comment: I meant bytes you're right ! Is there a good bytes counter around ?

Comment: How specifically do we have to handle whitespace? You say each element is `<space><odd-number><space>`, but the test cases don't have a space after the last odd number. Is it optional? Also, is the output for `n=0` two empty lines?

Comment: Last space is optional and n = 0 = empty line, you're right :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

05AB1E uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.
Saved 4 bytes thanks to *Adnan*.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to *carusocomputing*

```
ÅÉðìDg…/ \×»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4XDicOww6xEZ-KApi8gXMOXwrs&input=MTA)

**Explanation**

```
ÅÉ               # list of uneven number up to input
  ðì             # prepend a space to each
    Dg           # get length of list
      …/ \       # push the string "/ \"
          ×      # repeat the string length-list times
           »     # join rows by spaces and columns by newlines
```

Comment: HOW LONG HAS `Ï` EXISTED?! That seems suuuper useful.

Comment: @carusocomputing A long time :p

Comment: `LDÉÏ` is the same as `ÅÉ` and `„  ýðì` can be replaced by `ðì)»` :).

Comment: @Adnan: Nice! I didn't know about `ÅÉ`.

Comment: You can remove the `)`, can't you?

Comment: `ÅÉðìDg…/ \×»` uses `Dg` instead of `¹;î` for another byte save as well.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Nice catch!

Comment: Well done ! I think it's the shortest one :D

Answer (score 10):

### Pyke, 16 bytes

```
S2%idm+dJil*"/ \
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S2%25idm%2BdJil%2a%22%2F+%5C&input=10)

#### 17 bytes and more awesome

```
S2%i`~Bd.:il*"/ \
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S2%25i%60%7EBd.%3Ail%2a%22%2F+%5C&input=10)

This uses IMHO an AWESOME algorithm for making sure the first line is correctly aligned.

```
S                 - range(1, input+1)
 2%               -  ^[::2]
   i              -   i = ^
    `             -    str(^)
     ~Bd.:        -     ^.translate("><+-.,[]", " ") <-- awesome bit here
          il      -  len(i)
            *"/ \ - ^ * "/ \"
```

This replaces all the characters in the stringified list with spaces. `~B` contains all the characters in the Brain**** language and this is the first time I've used this variable.

The program `` `~Bd.: `` does this:

```
`~Bd.: - input = [1, 3, 5, 7]
`      - str(input)  # stack now ["[1, 3, 5, 7]"]
 ~B    - "><+-.,[]"  # stack now ["[1, 3, 5, 7]", "><+-.,[]"]
   d   - " "         # stack now ["[1, 3, 5, 7]", "><+-.,[]", " "]
    .: - translate() # stack now [" 1  3  5  7 "]
```

Comment: ...this is...just awesome? You know you just beat 05AB1E and everyone, right?

Comment: I have tried Jelly; it will surely be much longer.

Comment: "I used the BF charset to evenly space an array of numbers" The things you never thought you'd say...

Comment: This is really clever :) Well done

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー Not beating 05AB1E any more.

Answer (score 6):

## Python <s>2</s> 3, <s>67</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 60 Bytes

Nothing too crazy here, <s>I think the first section can probably be done shorter but I'm not quite sure how</s>. I use the fact that in this case `-~n/2` will work for `ceil`.

```py
lambda n:-~n//2*' %d '%(*range(1,n+1,2),)+'\n'+-~n//2*'/ \\'
```

Below are alternative 61 and 65 byte solutions in Python 2:

```py
lambda n:-~n/2*' %d '%tuple(range(1,n+1,2))+'\n'+-~n/2*'/ \\'
lambda n:' '+'  '.join(map(str,range(1,n+1,2)))+'\n'+-~n/2*'/ \\'
```

<sup>*Thanks to Rod for saving 2 bytes and Artyer for saving another byte by switching version :)*</sup>

Comment: If you move to Python 3, you can replace `%(tuple(...))` with `%[*...]`, but you would have to do `-~n//2`

Comment: @Artyer Tried this, but it throws a bunch of errors. I *think* I would need to cast `range` to a list because 3's `range` is like Python 2's `xrange`.

Comment: you can also drop the parentheses that are surrounding the `tuple()`

Comment: You can do `(*<iterable>,)` to cast to tuple in Python 3. This saves 1 byte though after you turn `n/2` into `n//2` for Python 3.

Comment: @Rod and Artyer thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 63 bytes

```python
lambda n:' '.join(n%2*`n`for n in range(n+1))+'\n'+-~n/2*'/ \\'
```

Little trick for the first line: it don't print the even numbers, but take them as an empty string, which leads to starting empty space (0 would be there), and double spaces between the numbers without any modification on the range, the downside is a leading space in the even numbered `n`

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```js
f=n=>n%2?f(n-1).replace(`
`,` ${n} 
/ \\`):n?f(n-1):`
`
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 max=10 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Note the space on the end of the second line.

Comment: Dangit, I thought `.replace` might be better but I didn't bother to check...

Comment: The question says "you **may** assume..."

Comment: @SolomonUcko The HTML is not part of the answer, it merely serves to demonstrate its operation. As such, it might as well limit the value to between 1 and 10, since the result wouldn't be valid otherwise.

Comment: I see. You would have to determine the correct spacing otherwise

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, <s>73</s> <s>59</s> 56 bytes

This is a really high byte count IMO for what seems like a simple problem.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
caw="/2*2
caw1357911/"
DYp:s;.;/ \\;g
k:s// & /g
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=AWNhdxI9EiIvMioyChsBY2F3MTM1NzkxMRsvEiIKRFlwOnM7LjsvIFxcO2cKazpzLy8gJiAvZwo&input=Ng)

Unprintables:

```
^Acaw^R=^R"/2*2      # Transform a number into the next odd number (3->5,4>5)
^[^Acaw1357911^[/^R" # Insert 1357911, delete everything after the number above
DYp:s;.;/ \\;g       # Duplicate the line, replace numbers with / \
k:s// & /g           # On the line above, add spaces around numbers
<trailing newline>
```

Comment: Nice, I always upvote vim! However, unprintable characters also count as bytes, so this solution really is 73 bytes. Sorry about that!

Comment: I do have some tips however. 1) If you use a different seperator on your substitute command, you won't need to escape the forward slash, so you can do `:s;.;/ \\;g`. 2) on your second substitute command, you can leave the search empty and it will use your last search (which just so happens to be the same). Also, `&` is equivalent to `\0` and one byte shorter. So you get `:s// & /g`

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to see a V answer from you to see if you used a different approach for fewer bytes, but that's alright!  The first comment, I think, is a function of me forgetting to update the Try it Online link.  The second got me 3 bytes, so thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:" 1  3  5  7  9"[:-~n/2*3]+'\n'+-~n/2*"/ \\"
```

Takes advantage of the restriction `n <= 10` to generate the top line by chopping off a piece from a hardcoded string.

The outputs for 1 to 10 are

```
 1 
/ \
 1 
/ \
 1  3 
/ \/ \
 1  3 
/ \/ \
 1  3  5 
/ \/ \/ \
 1  3  5 
/ \/ \/ \
 1  3  5  7 
/ \/ \/ \/ \
 1  3  5  7 
/ \/ \/ \/ \
 1  3  5  7  9
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
 1  3  5  7  9
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

The output for 0 is two empty lines.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 65 bytes

```
" "<>Range[1,#,2]~StringRiffle~"  "<>"
"<>"/ \\"~Table~⌈#/2⌉&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input and returns a string as output. The Unicode characters, respectively, are U+2308 LEFT CEILING for `\[LeftCeiling]` and U+2309 RIGHT CEILING for `\[RightCeiling]`.

Answer (score 4):

## WinDbg, 100 bytes

```
.echo;.for(r$t1=1;@$t1<=2*@$t0+@$t0%2;r$t1=@$t1+2){j@$t1<=@$t0 .printf"\b %d \n",@$t1;.printf"/ \\"}
```

Input is done by setting a value in the pseudo-register `$t0`.

Looks like it's shortest here just to print the string as it's being built rather than try to build it first and display the whole thing. I'd have a shorter solution if WinDbg would let me write to address `0`.

How it works:

```
.echo;                                            * Print a new line that'll be deleted
.for(r$t1=1; @$t1 <= 2*@$t0+@$t0%2; r$t1=@$t1+2)  * Enumerate 1 to 4*ceil($t0/2), count by 2
{
    j@$t1<=@$t0                                   * If $t1 <= $t0...
        .printf"\b %d \n",@$t1;                   * ...Print $t1 (and newline for last n)
        .printf"/ \\"                             * ...Else print the / \'s
}
```

Output for each value of `n`:

```
0:000> .for(r$t0=0;b>@$t0;r$t0=@$t0+1){.printf"\n\nn=%d\n",@$t0; .echo;.for(r$t1=1;@$t1<=2*@$t0+@$t0%2;r$t1=@$t1+2){j@$t1<=@$t0 .printf"\b %d \n",@$t1;.printf"/ \\"}}


n=0



n=1
 1 
/ \

n=2
 1 
/ \

n=3
 1  3 
/ \/ \

n=4
 1  3 
/ \/ \

n=5
 1  3  5 
/ \/ \/ \

n=6
 1  3  5 
/ \/ \/ \

n=7
 1  3  5  7 
/ \/ \/ \/ \

n=8
 1  3  5  7 
/ \/ \/ \/ \

n=9
 1  3  5  7  9 
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \

n=10
 1  3  5  7  9 
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <strike>118</strike> 112 Bytes

*Edit: Saved 6 Bytes thanks to @peech*

Golfed:

```
String M(int n){String o=" ";int i=1;n+=1;for(;i<n;i+=2)o+=i+"  ";o+="\n";for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)o+="/ \\";return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public String M(int n)
{
    String o = " ";
    int i=1;
    n += 1;
    for (; i < n;i+=2)
        o += i + "  ";
    o += "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        o += "/ \\";
    return o;  
}
```

Testing:

```
    OddMountains om = new OddMountains();
    System.out.println(om.M(1));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(om.M(3));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(om.M(5));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(om.M(7));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(om.M(10));

 1  
/ \

 1  3  
/ \/ \

 1  3  5  
/ \/ \/ \

 1  3  5  7  9  
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Comment: Ahhhh, you've beat me to it :) i also wanted to post a Java answer. anyhow, here are some suggestions to golf it a bit more: you dont need to initialize `i` in your first for loop, it could look like this `for(; i < n; i++)`. You can golf it even further with this change: `o += i + "  ";` changes to `o += i++ + "  ";` and for loop becomes `for(; i < n; )`. That is if you want to keep if statement. You could change your increment of i to `i += 2 ` and delete the whole if statement, but in that case my second proposition doesnt apply :) (ps: i havent tested this :) )

Comment: @peech If it's any consolation, it's normally a race for me to get the first C# answer in. If that's gone, I fumble my way through a Java answer :) Thanks for the tips. I've removed the `i` initialisation from the `for` loop, but the other things got it stuck in a loop. I might need to play around with it a little more :)

Comment: Huh, I'm so glad that in my previous comment I said "i havent tested this" ... of course it doesnt work with `o += i++ + " ";` :). Btw, you have a tiny bug in your code :) since Java uses `floor()` on integer division (4 / 3 = 1), you should do it like this: `int i = 1; n += 1; for (; i < n; i += 2) { ... jada jada ... }`. if you increment i by `i += 2`, you don't need that if statement checking for parity. It also saves another 3 bytes :)  try it here: https://ideone.com/ekaUUH

Comment: @peech If someone is confident enough to correct my code, I assume it must be right, so when it doesn't work, I try again and again, thinking "it must be me..." :) No worries! Thanks for the tips - I discovered the `floor` division quirk myself when playing with some Java a few days ago :)

Answer (score 4):

## ><> (FISH), <s>69</s> <s>60</s> <s>68</s> 55 bytes

```
5|v&+%1:,2
1->:?!v:
8~v!?l<on$o:*4
a&/o
1->:?!;"\ /"ooo
```

[Paste it into this online interpreter!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

The number 5 on the first line is your input value (hard coded as 5, replaced by 0-a or i for user input).

Edit 1: Moved new line placement into the first line space (was empty) to save 9 bytes overall on space from a new line.

Edit 2: As noted by user7150406 the output was wrong (no spaces printing) this has been fixed with a loss of 8 bytes.

Edit 3: completely changed the logic, there is no point checking if the number is odd - rather put all numbers on the stack and remove every second one. Byte saved 13!

Answer (score 3):

## C#6, 95 bytes

```
n=>{var o="";int i=1;for(;i<=n;i+=2)o+=$" {i} ";o+='\n';for(i=1;i<=n;i+=2)o+="/ \\";return o;};
```

Full lambda:

```
Func<int, string> a = n=>
{
    var o="";int i=1;
    for(;i<=n;i+=2)
        o+=$" {i} ";
    o+='\n';
    for(i=1;i<=n;i+=2)
        o+="/ \\";
    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
Sri,:)2%_S2**N@,"/ \\"*
```

[Test it!](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=Sri%2C%3A)2%25_S2**N%40%2C%22%2F%20%5C%5C%22*&input=10)

*-3 thanks to 8478 (Martin Ender)*

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by avoiding some of the stack manipulation: `Sri,:)2%_S2**N@,"/ \\"*`

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh, so that's why I couldn't remove that `+`. And I swear, I really used `ed`! ...shorter than Pyth.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
K-SQyMS5+dj*2dK*lK"/ \
```

*Thanks to 42545 (ETHproductions) for -1 byte*

[Online interpreter](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=K-SQyMS5%2Bdj%2a2dK%2alK%22%2F+%5C)

[11 test cases](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=K-SQyMS5%2Bdj%2a2dK%2alK%22%2F+%5C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10)

Comment: Save a quote with `*lK"/ \\ `

Comment: @ETHproductions You can then use ``\`` instead of ``\\`` :)

Answer (score 3):

### Game Maker Language (GM 8.0), 97 bytes

```
m=ceil(argument0/2)e=""for(i=1;i<2*m;i+=2)e+=" "+string(i)+" "return e+"#"+string_repeat("/ \",m)
```

Given that the input is at most 10, `chr(48+i)` will work in place of `string(i)`, although the number of bytes is the same.

Readable:

```
m = ceil(argument0/2)
e = ""
for (i = 1; i < 2*m; i += 2 )
  e += " " + string(i) + " "
return e + "#" + string_repeat("/ \", m)
```

Answer (score 3):

### ><> (Fish) <s>52</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
<v!?:-1:!?-1%2:
 >~la}}" "72.
v!?-2lno<o"  "
o
>:?!;"\ /"ooo1-
```

[Try it online!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/DyA4LoRgBNpqBdTS3)

To use simply place `n` on the stack and away you go!

Much of this is taken from @Teal-Pelican's answer :).

Edit: The output is actually not aligned correctly in either ><> submission! Fixing...

Edit2: I had to sacrifice some bytes, but the output is actually correct now.

Edit3: No more fun with `\` `/` mirrors and I save 1 byte.

**Output:**

```
 1  3  5  7  9
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error in the printing, I'm editing my answer now (fairly trivial for mine) it's interesting seeing the base answer the same but a lot of byte saves.

Comment: No problem, I was happy to see a ><> submission! It's gonna be interesting to see which one ends up being smaller now as these changes hurt mine pretty bad haha.

Comment: Looks like I'm juuuust 5 bytes smaller :p.

Comment: I'm going to have another look at mine now to see if I can squeeze a few mote bytes out aha.

Comment: I got home and had an idea for a new way to go about it. My new answer is 55 bytes! :D - Thanks for making me work on this, it's been fun.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>100</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```c
#define P(s)for(i=0;i++<n;printf(s,i++));puts("");
i;f(n){P(" %d ")P("/ \\")}
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 58 bytes

```r
cat(paste("",z<-seq(,scan(),2)),"\n");for(i in z)cat("/ \\")

3:
#>  1  3 
#> / \/ \

10:
#>  1  3  5  7  9 
#> / \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby <s>82</s> 60 Bytes

Quick and dirty Ruby solution could definitely be better optimized if I was better with Ruby

```
puts "",1.step($*[0].to_i,2).map{|x|$><<" #{x} ";"/ \\"}*""
```

Usage: prog.rb 10
Output:

```
 1  3  5  7  9
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

edit: numerous edits and optimisations by @Manatwork!

Comment: `print` → `$><<` and use string interpolation `" #{x} "`. But the best would be to reduce the number of `.each` by outputting the 1st line directly from the callback and building up the 2nd line in a variable: `s="";(1..$*[0].to_i).step(2){|x|$><<" #{x} ";s+="/ \\"};puts"",s`. Or even `puts"",(1..$*[0].to_i).step(2).map{|x|$><<" #{x} ";"/ \\"}*""`.

Comment: [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step) accepts 2 parameter, so can avoid the lengthy range syntax that requires parenthesis around: `(1..$*[0].to_i).step(2)` → `1.step($*[0].to_i,2)`.

Comment: @manatwork really good suggestions! I can see myself using a lot of your advice in my future codegolf posts so I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <del>64</del>, <del>59</del>, <del>57</del>, <del>51</del>, <del>49</del>, <del>48</del>, 45 bytes

EDIT:

- minus 3 bytes (use $1 instead of STDIN)
- one more byte off by replacing `-s ""` with `-s\`
- minus 2 bytes by replacing *printf* with *seq -f* (Thanks @Adam!)
- refactored to script instead of function (to beat the **><>**)
- removed superfluous spaces
- optimized the *sed* expression a bit

**Golfed**

Chunk (45 byte):

```
seq -f" %g " -s\  1 2 $1|sed 'p;s| . |/ \\|g'
```

Function (original version) (57 bytes):

```
M() { printf " %s %.0s" `seq 1 $1`|sed 'p;s| . |/ \\|g';}
```

**Test**

```
--- mountains.sh ----
#!/bin/bash
seq -f" %g " -s\  1 2 $1|sed 'p;s| . |/ \\|g'

>./mountains.sh 10
 1  3  5  7  9 
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \

>M 10
 1  3  5  7  9 
/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Comment: The `sed` is brilliant. By not using a function nor printf, you save 10 bytes : `seq -f" %g " -s "" 1 2 $1|sed 'p;s| . |/ \\|g'`

Comment: That's a nice advice ! Thank you ! I still use `cat` to read the input from STDIN, as IMO it is not really fair to use a pre-defined variable to pass the data in.

Comment: `$1` is just the first parameter transmitted to the program. I don't think it's cheating see http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods

Comment: Yep, you are correct. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge 93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 64 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=ICY2MXAxICAgdisyLCwsIi8gXCIKX3YjIWAiICI6PCsyLiwiICI6CiA8XnAwMHAxMCJ8PCIKQCA-OTErLCQxdg&input=OQ)

```
 &61p1   v+2,,,"/ \"
_v#!`" ":<+2.," ":
 <^p00p10"|<"
@ >91+,$1v
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```
n=>(f=n=>n?f(n-1)+(n%2?n+s:s):s=" ")(n)+`
`+"/ \\".repeat(++n/2)
```

Recursively builds the first line, then appends the second. The first line is built with the observation that it's simply the range **[0...n]** with each item **n** transformed to a space if even, or **n** concatenated with a space if odd.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 60 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Kade!

```py
lambda s:" "+"  ".join(`range(s+1)`[4::6])+"\n"+-~s/2*"/ \\"
```

Comment: You don't need to use a `list()` cast, removing it gets you to 60 :)

Comment: @Kade The backticks ```` make it a string. I can't do it like `lambda s:" "+"  ".join(range(s+1)[1::2])+"\n"+-~s/2*"/ \\"e` because then it would give a list of ints and it dies

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr7n8.png)

Comment: @Kade Huh. It doesn't work online... **Never mind, I don't know why I thought it didn't work...**

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 107 bytes

```
@set s=
@set t=
@for /l %%i in (1,2,%1)do @call set s=%%s%%  %%i&call set t=%%t%%/ \
@echo%s%
@echo %t%
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>99</strike> 95 Bytes

```
(? :Int)=>for(i<-0 to 1)println(1 to ?filter(c=>c%2>0)map(c=>if(i<1)s" $c "else"/ \\")mkString)
```

Ungolfed

```
(? :Int) => 
    for (i<-0 to 1)
        println(
            1 to ?filter(c=>c%2>0)
                  map(c=>if(i<1)s" $c "else"/ \\")
                  mkString
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 48 bytes

```
->x{" 1  3  5  7  9 "[0..3*x-=x/2]+?\n+"/ \\"*x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 45 bytes

`f=@(n)reshape(sprintf(' /%d  \',1:2:n),2,[]);`

Test:
f(8)

```
 1  3  5  7
/ \/ \/ \/ \
```

Comment: When input = 0, there is a / left :)

Comment: Didn't said your answer isn't correct ! Just noticed that small funny glitch :)

Comment: I can not assume n==0 :(

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4clFlNEYwWGxEVnc), 35 bytes

```
:[1,a,2|X=X+!b$+@ | Y=Y+@/ \|]?X ?Y
```

Explanation:

```
:           gets a CMD line param as INT 'a'
[1,a,2|     FOR b = 1 to a STEP 2
X=X+!b$+@ | Add to X$ the counter of our FOR loop and a trailing space
            Leading space is provided by the cast-to-string function.
Y=Y+@/ \|   Add to Y$ the mountain.
]           Close the first possible language construct (IF, DO or FOR). In this case: NEXT
?X ?Y       Print X$, Print Y$. The space adds a newline in the resulting QBASIC.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kitanai](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Kitanai), 140 bytes

```
$0[0]$1[int(input":")]$2[""]$3[""]$0#?(mod@2)($2[add(add(@" ")(string($0@)))"  "]
$3[add@"/ \"])?(neq@($1@))([add@1]&1)print($2@)print($3@)%
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 46 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = 48 bytes

```
@_=map$_%2?$_:"",0..$_;$_="@_$/"."/ \\"x(@_/2)
```

Using:

```
perl -ple '@_=map$_%2?$_:"",0..$_;$_="@_$/"."/ \\"x(@_/2)' <<< 7
```

Or 52 bytes:

```
@_=map$_%2?$_:"",0..pop;print"@_$/","/ \\"x(@_/2),$/
```

Using:

```
perl -e '@_=map$_%2?$_:"",0..pop;print"@_$/","/ \\"x(@_/2),$/' 7
```