# That's one odd mountain!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

<sup>Inspired by [*Display a chain of little mountains with an odd number on the top of it!*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100858/display-a-chain-of-little-mountains-with-an-odd-number-on-the-top-of-it) by [@sygmei](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62626/sygmei).</sup>

Why have a chain of mountains when you can have one massive one?

Make a program that takes an input number and prints a mountain with every odd number up to the input number.

(Where "south west" means `directly below and to the left`, and "south east" means `directly below and to the right`)

Every number will have a `/` south west of it, and a `\` south east. It starts from `1` at the top, and the next number will go south west of a `/` or south east of a `\`. The next number will go in the line closest to the top and to the left most possible.

For a multidigit number, just the 1st digit needs to be in the right place with the other digits directly after, and only the first digit should have `\` and `/` coming out from it.

The mountain up to 1 or 2 is just:

```
 1
/ \
```

A mountain up to 3 or 4 is just:

```
   1
  / \
 3
/ \
```

For 25 or 26:

```
         1
        / \
       3   5
      / \ / \
     7   9   11
    / \ / \ / \
   13  15  17  19
  / \ / \ / \ / \
 21  23  25
/ \ / \ / \
```

Last two lines where the input is 121:

```
 111 113 115 117 119 121
/ \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
```

And the last two lines where the input is 1019:

```
 993 995 997 999 1001100310051007100910111013101510171019
/ \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
```

You may assume that the input will be greater than 0 and less than 10001 (exclusive).

Trailing spaces are OK, and extra leading spaces are alright as long as there is the same on all lines.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

An ungolfed answer to this can be found online [here](https://repl.it/E6aT/0) (In Python on repl.it) if you need more test cases.

Comment: If the input is less than 101, then why do you have a 121 testcase?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I meant 10001, fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: Harder than the original one, I'll give it a try :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>54</s> <s>52</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
ÅÉ¹L£D€g__ÏRv"/ \ "yg×N·©úˆyvy4yg-ð×}J®>úˆ}¯R»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4XDicK5TMKjROKCrGdfX8OPUnYiLyBcICJ5Z8OXTsK3wqnDusuGeXZ5NHlnLcOww5d9SsKuPsO6y4Z9wq9Swrs&input=MTAyMA)

**Explanation**

```
                                                # implicit input n
ÅÉ                                              # push a list of uneven numbers up to input
  ¹L£                                           # divide into sublists of length 1,2,3...n
     D€g__Ï                                     # remove empty sublists
           R                                    # reverse list
            v                                   # for each sublist
             "/ \ "                             # push the string "/ \ "
                   yg×                          # repeat it len(sublist) times
                      N·©ú                      # prepend (sublist index)*2 spaces
                          ˆ                     # add to global list
                           yv                   # for each number in sublist
                             y4yg-ð×            # prepend spaces until length is 4
                                    }           # end inner loop
                                     J          # join to string
                                      ®>ú       # prepend (sublist index)*2+1 spaces
                                         ˆ      # add to global list
                                          }     # end outer loop
                                           ¯    # push global list
                                            R   # reverse it
                                             »  # join rows by space and columns by newline
                                                # implicitly print
```

I could have saved 5 bytes with `ÅÉ¹L£D€g__ÏRv"/ \ "yg×N·©úˆy4jJðÛ®>úˆ}¯R»` if only I'd pushed that bugfix for **j** I wrote several weeks ago **:/**

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 335 bytes

```
@echo off
set i=
set/ac=w=0
:l
set i=  %i%
set/aw+=2,c+=w
if %c% lss %1 goto l
set s=
set t=
set/ac=w=1
for /l %%a in (1,2,%1) do call:c %%a
echo  %s%
echo%t%
exit/b
:c
if not %c%==0 goto g
echo%i%%s%
set i=%i:~2%
echo%i%%t%
set s=
set t=
set/aw+=1,c=w
:g
set n=%1   (three trailing spaces)
set s=%s%%n:~0,4%
set t=%t% / \
set/ac-=1
```

Comment: @Artyer I'm pretty sure `cmd /Q /C file.bat` counts 3 extra bytes, but it's still better than `@echo off`. You should post that to the Batch tips question.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>160</s> <s>149</s> 143 bytes

<sup>*Thanks TFeld for saving 11 bytes and Artyer for saving 6 bytes*</sup>

```python
x=range(1,input()+1,2);y=[];i=1
while x:y+=[''.join('%-4d'%j for j in x[:i]),'/ \ '*len(x[:i])];x=x[i:];i+=1
while y:print' '*~-len(y)+y.pop(0)
```

Comment: You can do `i=len(y)` and `for l in y:print' '*i+l;i-=1` instead of `for i,l in enumerate(y):print(len(y)-i-1)*' '+l` for -10 bytes

Comment: Also I think you can change `\\ ` to `\ ` since it is before a space

Comment: You can change the last 2 lines to `while y:print' '*-~len(y)+y.pop(0)`. It saves 3 bytes.

Comment: And `''.join('%4d'%j for j in x[:i])` on the second line

Comment: @Artyer but that would break (hard) the alignment :c

Comment: @Rod Oops... I meant `%-4d` to left justify it by 4.

Comment: @Artyer woah, this negative value to left justify is new to me :D, nice trick

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 134

**133 bytes + 1 for `-p` option**

```
 $l="/ \\ ";$t=" ";while($c++<$_) {$t.=sprintf'%-4d',$c++;$v.=$l;if ($i++>=$j){$t=~s/^/  /gm;$t.="
  $v
 ";$i=$v="";$j++}}$_="$t
$v";
```

Formatted version (original golfed version uses real "new lines" instead of \n)

```
$l="/ \\ ";
$t=" ";
while($c++<$_) {
   $t.=sprintf'%-4d',$c++;
   $v.=$l;
   if ($i++>=$j){
      $t=~s/^/  /gm;
      $t.="\n  $v\n ";
      $i=$v="";
      $j++
   }
}
$_="$t\n$v";
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 425 bytes

```
f() { k=0; o=""; l=1; for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ )); do o="$o$c "; let c++ k++; if [ $l -eq $k ]; then o=$o"\n"; k=0; let l++; fi; done; s=$[$(echo -e $o | wc -l)*2-1]; p() { for c in $(seq $1); do echo -n " "; done }; IFS=$'\n'; for n in $(echo -e $o); do unset IFS; p $s; let s--; for w in $n; do echo -n "$w"; p $[4-${#w}]; done; echo; p $s; for c in $(seq $(echo $n|wc -w)); do echo -n "/ \ "; done; echo; let s-- j++; done }
```

Formatted:

```
l=1
k=0
o=""
for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ ))
do
        o="$o$c "
        let c++ k++
        if [ $l -eq $k ]
        then
                o=$o"\n"
                k=0
                let l++
        fi
done
s=$[$(echo -e $o | wc -l)*2-1]
p() {
        for c in $(seq $1)
        do
                echo -n " "
        done
}
IFS=$'\n'
for n in $(echo -e $o)
do
        unset IFS
        p $s
        let s--
        for w in $n
        do
                echo -n "$w"
                p $[4-${#w}]
        done
        echo
        p $s
        for c in $(seq $(echo $n|wc -w))
                do echo -n "/ \ "
        done
        echo
        let s-- j++
done
```